# Detect smartphone type

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

I am building a web application that will manipulate images. ( crop and apply effects like sepia etc ).

Is there a library where i can detect ( front or backend ), the type of device the user is using ( middle level device or high end. ).

Example an ipad would be a high end device, a nexus 5 from 2013, would be a mid level device.

On an nexus 5 from 2013 i would compress the image in javascript so it is being handled without lag, however on an ipad there would be no reason to do that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following link may be useful.

Refer to https://github.com/WhichBrowser/Parser